# Ethereum miner don't start

Tags: go-ethereum, mining-pools

I want to try to mine ethereum.
Its only a Test if it's working.
I am new to Ethereum. I am only mining Bitcoin.

So I installed the ethereum miner.

And want to mine in the f2pool.
In the help "Simply point your stratum-compatible miner to `zec.f2pool.com:3357`, `eth.f2pool.com:8008` or `etc.f2pool.com:8008`, and set your ethereum account as login"

So I tried (my username is wiraport) whats about the password

```
ethminer -F http://etc.f2pool.com:8008/wiraport -C -t 4
```

I got the following error.

> 13:05:58.486|ethminer  Getting work package...   ✘
>   13:05:58.981|ethminer  Failed to submit hashrate.   ✘
>   13:05:58.981|ethminer  Dynamic exception type:
>   jsonrpc::JsonRpcException std::exception::what: Exception -32003 :
>   Client connector error: libcurl error: 56

Whats that and how can I fix it?